# Connecting to OpenShift via Device

Tags: php, mysql, openshift

Good afternoon all;

I am developing an application for a project that utilizes an OpenShift MySQL Database. At the moment, I have written php scripts that ping the database on our host website, which, is also hosted on OpenShift.

My fear is that anyone can call this php address and either a) DDoS my DB/website, or b) can access or get any data inside said DB. There is nothing highly critical on this database, such as passwords and all, but it's best using best practices.

To my question: Is there a way to directly connect to this DB via various platforms such as iOS, Android, and Desktop (Mac, PC, Linux) and not use php scripts? I am somewhat familiar with OpenShift's PortForwarding, but I believe this is not what I am looking for.

If it is not possible to connect to said DB in this way, is there a way to make this process of getting data from the DB more secure?

Note on my php scripts:
They connect to the DB using a username and password. This user has only select and edit privileges. The purpose is to get fields of data: Building and Amount, and at times changes Amount, based on arguments of the php address. The returned data is encoded using JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for NodePort feature in openshift/k8s, that should allow connections if this is a self hosted openshift